# Using Script Editor and/or Content Editor Web Parts Alongside an Infopath Form?

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery, spservices

First some info about the system I'm working in:

Sharepoint Server 2013 on-premise

Sharepoint Designer 2013

Infopath Designer

No access to Power Apps

I'm new to Sharepoint. I also know very, very little code, but using google, I've managed to figure out enough to use jquery and spservices (via Script Editor Web Parts and Content Editor Web Parts), to create a form that suits my needs with cascading lookups, hiding fields based on the values in other fields, et cetera.

My problem is that when I use Infopath Designer to customize the form, rearrange/resize the fields, all that stuff, the Script/Content Editor Web Parts no longer work.

I've done some googling and found that this is to be expected; I don't really understand why, exactly, but something about Infopath not utilizing javascript.

My question is, is there some other way to "visually" arrange the form fields how I want them? A way that will still work with my Script/Content Editor Web Parts? It seems I can open up and edit the actual code of the form in Sharepoint Designer 2013, but editing the raw code is beyond me.

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit1: So, I think I have a little better understanding of the problem. It seems that the Script Editor Web Parts are working fine. What's not working is the Content Editor Web Part, which I have set up to link to a script in an html file. I'm reading that maybe Infopath forms do not load at the same time as the rest of the page, and because of this using jquery's "$(document).ready()" does not work. I'm not sure what the solution is to that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option will be to use InfoPath's out-of-the-box styling to change the look and feel of your forms. The HTML generated by InfoPath is fairly complex and getting the order of execution right for your JavaScript, alongside the InfoPath form rendering is tricky.

Realistically, I would recommend upgrading from SharePoint 2013 altogether, as it has already passed it's [end of life](https://learn.microsoft.com/lifecycle/products/sharepoint-server-2013).